# create mysql a stored procedure from file

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create  a stored procedure using PHP.  My reading indicates the best way to do this by running the .sql file using the 'exec' command in PHP.

In testing i created a file named amtv3_create_routines.sql with this contents:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS createTc //
CREATE PROCEDURE createTc()
BEGIN
    drop table if exists v3_tc;

    CREATE TABLE v3_tc (
        source BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
        dest BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY (source, dest) )
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

    insert into v3_tc (source, dest)
        select distinct rel.sourceid, rel.destinationid
        from rf2_ss_relationships rel inner join rf2_ss_concepts con
            on rel.sourceid = con.id and con.active = 1
        where rel.typeid = (select distinct conceptid from rf2_ss_descriptions where term = 'is a')
        and rel.active = 1;

    REPEAT

        insert into v3_tc (source, dest)
            select distinct b.source, a.dest
            from v3_tc a
            join v3_tc b on a.source = b.dest
            left join v3_tc c on c.source = b.source and c.dest = a.dest
            where c.source is null;

        set @x = row_count();

        select concat('Inserted ', @x);

    UNTIL @x = 0 END REPEAT;
    create index idx_v3_tc_source on v3_tc (source);
    create index idx_v3_tc_dest on v3_tc (dest);
END //
DELIMITER;
```

This code works fine when I manually enter it into mysql 5.6.22
However if I save the file and from the prompt enter the command.

```
mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost amtv3  < [full path]/amtv3_create_routines.sql
```

I have tried saving the file using utf8 encoding and windows 1252 encoding.

From the command prompt, there is no feedback, and the procedure is not created.
In PHP I am using the codeigniter framework. If I use the `db->query` method I can create the stored procedure, however the database loses connection. issuing `$db->reconnect()` works, but not reliably.

Any suggestions on how to create the stored procedure?

Comment: You would need to specify the database where you want to store the procedure in.

Comment: I use the amtv3 database in the command prompt. i have also issued the use amtv3; in the file.  both don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Omitting the space in the last line, `DELIMITER;` should result in a syntax error (there may be some other reason why this error is not being printed).

Answer (score 0):

`DELIMITER` is only a feature of certain MySQL clients, and not a feature of the server. Therefore, when executing a .sql file directly, the server will interpret the first semi-colon as the end of the first statement and `DELIMITER //` will be seen as a syntax violation:

> Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
> CREATE PROCEDURE . . .

Discovered this here:
https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/issues/351#issuecomment-120081608

**The Solution?**
Simply don't change the delimiter. The `BEGIN` and `END` already delimit a compound statement.

Source:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_begin_end_compound.htm

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
mysql -h localhost -U <username> -d <database_name> -f /home/user/<procedure_name>.sql
```

Comment: the -U should be lower case -u , -d shoudl be upper case -D